# How to filter ManyToMany field in Django queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models:

```py
class VideoParameter(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="parameter_tag")
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Video(TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parameters = models.ManyToManyField(VideoParameter, related_name="video_parameter")
    url = models.URLField(verbose_name=_('Url'))
```

(I mean that a video have some parameters like Key-Value (ex. {"rabbit": 1, "panda": 1, "lion": 0}))

Then I am trying to get the video, specified by query parameter.

(like this `/video/?rabbit=1&panda=1&lion=0`)

The SQL code that I want to do is belows:

```sql
SELECT app_video.id, count(*) AS match_count FROM app_video 
INNER JOIN app_video_parameters on app_video.id = app_video_parameters.video_id
INNER JOIN app_videoparameter ON app_video_parameters.videoparameter_id = app_videoparameter.id 
WHERE (app_videoparameter.member_id = 1 AND app_videoparameter.value = 0) 
OR (app_videoparameter.member_id = 9 AND app_videoparameter.value = 1)
OR (app_videoparameter.member_id = 11 AND app_videoparameter.value = 1)
...
GROUP BY (app_video.id) 
ORDER BY match_count DESC;
```

How can I realize this process in Django queryset?

Comment: So *any* of the items is sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

You can first construct a `Q` object with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

data = {'rabbit': 1, 'panda': 1, 'lion': 0}
q = Q(
    *[
        Q(parameters__member__name=k, parameters__value=v)
        for k, v in data.items()
    ],
    _connector=Q.OR
)
Video.objects.filter(q).annotate(
    match_count=Count('parameters')
).order_by('-match_count')
```